# Convert an integral equation in an initial value problem of an ODE of degree 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

The following exercise is a part of a bigger exercise. Therefore I first give you the setting of the whole exercise and then (in the grey box below) the part of the exercise which I mean here.

Setting of the whole exercise:

Consider $-\infty<a<b< +\infty, F\in C([a,b]^2\times\mathbb{R}), f\in C([a,b])$ with
$$
\exists L\geq 0~\forall x,y\in[a,b]~\forall u,v\in\mathbb{R}:~~\lvert F(x,y,u)-F(x,y,v)\rvert\leq L~\lvert u-v\rvert.
$$
Furthermore consider the non-linear operator $T\colon C([a,b])\to C([a,b])$ given by
$$
T(u)(x):=\int_a^xF(x,y,u(y))\, dy+f(x)~~\text{for}~~x\in [a,b].
$$

> > Consider the special case $a:=0, b:=1, F(x,y,u):=xyu, f(x):=1$ and the integral equation
> >     $$
> > u(x)-\int_a^x F(x,y,u(y))\, dy+f(x)~~~~~\text{for }x\in [a,b].
> > $$
> >     Transfer the integral equation for the given special case in an equivalent initial value problem of an ODE of degree 2 on $[0,1]$.

Could you please explain me, how I can make an initial value problem out of the given integral equation that is in the special case
$$
u(x)-\int_0^x xyu(y)\, dy=1~~~~~\text{for }x\in [0,1]?
$$

What is searched is something like

$$
y''=F(x,y(x),y'(x)), y(x_0)=y_0, y'(x_0)=y_0'
$$

but I do not know how to reach that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your $u$, provided $u$ is well-behaved near $y=0$, one has $u(0)=0$, and
$$
    u' = \frac{d}{dx}\left(x\int_{0}^{x}yu(y)\,dy\right).
$$
Keep going with that and see where it leads. Remember, you can use $u=1+x\int_{0}^{x}yu(y)dy$ if you need to.

Comment: I have $u'(x)=\int_0^x y u(y)\, dy + x^2u(x)$, so $u'(0)=0$. Furthermore I have $u''(x)=xu(x)+2xu(x)+x^2u'(x)$. So is the equivalent initial value problem given by $u''=g(x,u,u'), u(0)=0, u'(0)=0$ with $g(x,u,u')=xu(x)+2xu(x)+x^2u'(x)$? Or is that too simple?

Comment: @math12: That looks right to me.

Comment: That's all the exercise? Thought it would be more difficult.